# How do I make a function run when a program finishes in Python?

Tags: python

I have a function I want to run whenever there is nothing else for the program to do. How do I implement this?

Comment: call it at the end of the script

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Please provide a [mcve] including an explanation of the specific problem, _code_ for what you've tried based on your own research, and a description of what went wrong with your attempt(s). This will help us understand how to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def yourFunction(): 
    stuff

yourFunction()
```

Answer (score 0):

The `atexit` module may be what you are looking for.